# can we change bind adress of http protocol of influx db

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, http-protocols

I'm trying to change [http] protocol's bind address,using which im able to send out the results but im not able to access iflux CLI.

I tried to change the bind address of [http] from 8086 to other numbers.But i'm not able to access influx CLI .However when i have bind address of 8086, i can access influx CLI.

I may have to change the bind address from 8086 to any other ,as this port has been already under use by other service .

Please can anyone help me on how can i change the [http] bind address on which i can use influx CLI.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If it's ok you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it. Thanks

Comment: @ UBIK LOAD PACK ..sorry for the delayed reply.Was on a holiday.Please find my comment to your answer.Thankyou.Much respect to your kind reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select a free port by running:

> netstat -an | grep NEW_PORT_NUMBER

If nothing is output, it's free.

Then open /usr/local/etc/influxdb.conf, search for [http] and modify:

> # bind-address = ":8086"

to

> bind-address = ":NEW_PORT_NUMBER"

Restart JMeter

If you're accessing it from another machine, check firewall is open for this NEW_PORT_NUMBER.

To access it :

> influx -port NEW_PORT_NUMBER -host hostname

Comment: Hi @UBIK, Question i asked mainly to know is, if i change the http bind address im not able to access Influxdb CLI.i'm able to change the bind address of http to new unused port.

Comment: ..As you may be aware that in the latest influxdb release we dont not have admin interface.SO CLI is the only option to create edit influxdb databases etc

Comment: @ UBIK LOAD PACK thankyou..I did accept the answer also.